# How to sell property back to seller after 30 days

Tags: united-states, taxes, house, texas, land

I purchased a lot with a condemned house on it from a friend for $27,000. I put down $1000 on it. They are financing for me.  I no longer want the property and they are willing to reverse the sale or buy it back from me.  What kind of paperwork do we need to do this properly? They sent me a Texas General Warranty Deed with their purchase price being $1500 to buy it back and I was going to notarize it but then I started thinking about legalities and taxes, etc.
Thank you for your help.  Lenora

Comment: Sell it back the same way they sold it to you?

Comment: Have you paid the $26,000? If not you haven't bought it yet. Just get your $1000 back and sign an agreement that any previous sale agreement is cancelled.

Comment: Thank you, I have not paid the 26,000, I filed a Texas General Warranty Deed with the County.  Do I need to cancel that? and if so how do I do that?